.Net collection performance for special use case
I am looking for a good starting point for my use case.
My use case is somewhat special so a simple performance test with all the collections available will not do it.
Performance is everything. Memory consumption can be as high as needed, I do not care.
Note: I already tried a few things with SortedDictionary instances. But I am wondering if some other collections would be a better fit. I also will implement a solution myself if there is a superior algorithm for handling these things, so there is no need to stick to existing implementations.
The use case is.
There is some data structure in the form {BigInterger key1, Guid key2, BigInteger quantity}. The Guid is not random but generated so that each new Guid is of higher value than the last one.
Note: I started with a SortedDictionary using key1 as key and holding an other SortedDictionary using key2 as key, but I came to the conclusion that maybe a more flat data structure with only one SortedDictonary using key1+key2 would be better.
The requirements are

Inserts can be random, however most inserts will happen in the top 100 items sorted based on the key. Inserts are always single items.
Remove of items will always remove the top n items first. So from a remove point of view the collection is like a stack. Remove always removes 1 to n items.
Lookups are not random but will return all top n items with keys lower or equal the lookup key
Lookup should also filter based on the quantity. So the lookup will take a quantity parameter. Items are return as long as the quantities of all items return does not exceed the lookup quantity. In addition, all returned items will be removed from the collection.
An Insert/Remove operation is always happening after a lookup operation. Possible operation chains are (lookup [15%], lookup->insert [15%], lookup->remove [15%], lookup->remove->insert [55%]). The probabilities are guesses there is no real way to tell beforehand what will happen more often.
The collection will be handling between 1 and 100 million items. Maybe even more.

Note: I did also thought about using a linked list. maybe they are better suited for this than a SortedDictionary.
What would be your approach for this.
Note: Current State: Comparing performance between 'SortedDictionary<BigInteger, SortedDictionary<Guid, OrderData>>' and SortedDictionary<MergedKey, OrderData>
Results so far



Solution
Number of Items
Inserts / second




SortedDictionary with embedded SortedDictionary
1
847


SortedDictionary with embedded SortedDictionary
1M
2000000


SortedDictionary with embedded SortedDictionary
10M
87719


SortedDictionary with embedded SortedDictionary
100M
4677


ImmutableSortedDictionary with embedded ImmutableSortedDictionary
1
410


ImmutableSortedDictionary with embedded ImmutableSortedDictionary
1M
666666


ImmutableSortedDictionary with embedded ImmutableSortedDictionary
10M
20491


ImmutableSortedDictionary  with embedded ImmutableSortedDictionary
100M
1406


SortedDictionary with CombinedKey
1
1288


SortedDictionary with CombinedKey
1M
769230


SortedDictionary with CombinedKey
10M
44444


SortedDictionary with CombinedKey
100M
2557


ImmutableSortedDictionary with CombinedKey
1
2105


ImmutableSortedDictionary with CombinedKey
1M
370370


ImmutableSortedDictionary with CombinedKey
10M
14204


ImmutableSortedDictionary  with CombinedKey
100M
1047




If performance is key then what operation has the most relevance. Insert,Remove,Lookup?  You wont get "optimal" behavior for all 3 operations at the same time. So you need to decide.

I did also thought about using a linked list - Linked lists tend to be terrible for cache efficiency, and that is a very important concern. Your use case sound like it should be fairly cache friendly since it seem mostly like the top is accessed most frequently.

Your question mention keys, but you have two keys, which is used for lookup? Do you really need to use BigInt? If you can get away with an int64 or int128 it may greatly help with data locality and memory use. Knowing the distribution of quantities as well as expected query values may also help.

Using a sorted array
Lets consider the algorithmic complexity of your operations using a sorted (dynamic) array. Lets also assume there is a single key used for sorting and lookup.

Inserts can be random, however most inserts will happen in the top 100 items sorted based on the key. Inserts are always single items.

So the typical case require moving ~50 items, i.e. O(1), and I would not worry to much of the time constant for 50 items. Worst case would be O(n). There is also the reallocation penalty for dynamic arrays, but this can be avoided by setting a large enough initial capacity.

Remove of items will always remove the top n items first. So from a remove point of view the collection is like a stack. Remove always removes 1 to n items.

This should take a constant time i.e. O(1), since you would only be modifying the count property.

Lookups are not random but will return all top n items with keys lower or equal the lookup key

This would mean a binary search to find the largest key lower than the lookup key, O(log n), and then it should be trivial to return a span for the given range.

Lookup should also filter based on the quantity. So the lookup will take a quantity parameter. Items are return as long as the quantities of all items return does not exceed the lookup quantity. In addition, all returned items will be removed from the collection.

If I understand this correctly you still do a binary search as above, followed by iterating values until the sum of the quantities equal the query value. This should take O(log n + m) where m is the number of items returned.
Conclusion
Most operations should be O(log n) or better, and this is quite good. Even if there are data structures supporting O(1) you need to consider the time constant. Actual runtime may greatly depend on efficient cache usage.
As far as I know there is no builtin collection that supports all of these operations efficiently out of the box. So I would probably just roll my own using a List<T> or a plain array as the backing storage, there is existing binary search methods for both List and Array that could be used. Array allow for lower level access, but require you to handle increases in size yourself if that is needed.
If profiling suggest that inserts take to much time, due to the O(n) worst case), you might want to look at something like a skip list, or unrolled linked list. But I have not enough experience with these to suggest anything specific.
Other notes
I would try to stay away from BigInt if performance is a concern. For values less than 32 bits a BigInt will use 12 bytes. For values in the 32-64 bit range it will use 36 bytes. BigInt are also slower, since operations will involve loops and branches. So if you can use fixed size types like int64 or int128 it might greatly help with cache usage and performance.  If values larger than int128 exist but are rare it might be better to handle these as a special case.
I would probably recommend using a struct instead of class, to reduce memory usage and indirection. You can use Span, in parameters etc to reduce copy overhead.
I would recommend Benchmark .net for evaluation. This should help ensure good measurements. Just make sure to write representative test cases.

It's not only that BigInteger uses a lot of memory, it's that its operations are VERY slow. They all use loops and byte-by-byte processing, and you'll be doing a lot of hashing (in the original dictionary code, not in yours), equality checks and comparisons. There also are specialized Int256 implementations using AVX2 that show over 20x improvements over BigInteger.

Thanks for the input.
At the moment I do experiment with a skip list variant to see if it gives any benefits. I did not know about unrolled linked lists but I will look into it.
In fact I already use struct as data container to reduce memory usage.
I will definitely look into benchmark.net. At the moment I use MSTest with StopWatch for that.
Unfortunately I can not get rid if BigInteger, key1 in my example is a value representing a number with 18 decimals stored as natural number just multiplied by 10^18. I do not know of any other datatype that can hold such big numbers.

@Blindy oh a Int256 and even an UInt256 Datatype. Thats interesting. And I think it will be big enough too... thanks for the tipp.

@lamanSwtrse uint64 should support up to 1.8446744e+19, uint128 will handle 3.4028237e+38. So 18 decimal digits should not be a problem. But if it is a "key", does it really need to be an actual number, and not just supporting a limited set of operations, like equality and comparison? And for "quantity", what is it you are counting where 1e+38 is insufficient, but you still need an exact count?

@Blindy Short update. I just replaced BigInteger with UInt256 and I Used a Key struct that only provides the compare functions needed for the combined key instead of BigInteger (UInt256 was too small). I did than run the Insert tests. However the result is slightly unexpected.
While the time needed to add 1 item is halved in every case. Adding 1M, 10M, 100M items show either exactly the same performance as the BigInteger variant or slightly worse performance. Can be my test cases but they are basically only for loops calling the Insert method the requested amount of times.

@JonasH The values can go high on the left side of the decimal point too. Technically ethereum contracts store token amounts in an uint256 datatype so this would be the upper bound in this case. However My tests show that the Uint256 implementation of Nethereum does not hold any performance benefits against BigInteger at least if stuffed into an SortedDictionary.
For the key to be unique I would need uint256+uint128 (the value used in the contract+guid).
Even if we say numbers will never get as high. But the values in the contract can and my c# library should be able to handle that.

@all Thanks for all the input especially the tip with BenchmarkDotNet that I did not know before. I did refine my benchmarks using BenchmarkDotNet now. That did clear many things up even if writing the benchmarks in the right way was a bit tricky.
I am at the moment experimenting with 3 custom collection types

SkipList
CacheSensitiveSkipList
Usecase optimized cache sensitive skip list
With 2 and 3 looking very promising.

